# Beamer - How to remove sections form headline (Frankfurt theme)

Tags: beamer, themes, markdown

I want to remove specific sections from the headline overview of the Frankfurt theme in beamer. A MWE would be this:

```tex
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\section{Backup slides}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{References}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: section headers to remove]

How can I remove the "Back up slide" and "Reference" sections from the headline? I dont need these in the overview for the presentation. The rest of the overview could be stretched, or I could place logos in the freed-up space.

Addon to the question: Ultimately, I am writing this presentation in pandoc markdown and converting to a slide show. Maybe there is a tex way to remove the sections from the header using the `include-in-header` option of pandoc, but perhaps its also possible to modify the markdown section headers to achieve the same?

Markdown MWE:

```markdown
---
slide-level: 2
theme: "Frankfurt"
...


# Section 1

## Slide 1

## Slide 2


# Section 2 

## Slide 1

## Slide 2


# Section 3

## Slide 1

## Slide 2


# Backup-slides

## Slide 1

## Slide 2


# References

## Slide 1

## Slide 2
```

compilied with `pandoc -s mwe.md -t beamer -o mwe_md.pdf`

I have tried

```markdown
# Backup slides {.unnumbered}

# Backup slides {.unnumbered .unlisted}

# Backup slides {.noframenumbering}
```

but without success. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can place the additional section in the `\appendix`:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\appendix
\section{Backup slides}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\section{References}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great. Also in markdown. I can just directly put `\appendix` before the `# Backup-slides` header in the markdown file. Thanks!

Comment: @flurble You're welcome!